# Eliminate shadow on rasterized text in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, raster, shadows

*First of all, I could not find anything matching my problem, probably because of the lack of better keywords.*

I created a word with the *Text Tool* and rasterized it for cropping and editing. But now the text appears to have a weird gray "border" around some parts.

You can see the difference here, as I have added a solid colored rectangle next to the part with the "border" (on the left size is the rectangle).

[image: Rectangle next to rasterized text]

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot really follow your example in the image. However, the problem may be due to anti-aliasing which exists in the type and in the rasterized image. When rasterized the anti-aliasing may become stronger and more visible. If you have to edit your type layer in rasterized form, you may consider:

1. Set it much larger type size than needed, say 144 points even if you need 24 points
2. In the Type menu, change Anti-Aliasing to "Smooth"
3. Rasterize this large text
4. Do the edits on the raster image
5. Then scale it down to needed size

This will make working on the text easier and hide small imperfections that may occur in the raster image editing by down-sampling it significantly. Of course, the best is to convert the type to a shape and edit it in vector format.